# How to iterate in mongodb aggregate cursor using vertx mongo client

Tags: mongodb, vert.x

I'm performing an aggregation using vertx mongo client, using the `runCommand` method.  Because it's mandatory to use a cursor, I'm adding `.put("cursor", new JsonObject().put("batchSize", xxx))` to the command but i have no idea about how to iterate over the cursor. How should I proceed?

Comment: `it's mandatory to use a cursor` why?

Comment: "Changed in version 3.6: MongoDB 3.6 removes the use of aggregate command without the cursor option unless the command includes the explain option. Unless you include the explain option, you must specify the cursor option.". This is written in mongodb docummentation

Answer (score 0):

The paragraphs you mention relate to the command-line use.

In vertx the `org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-async:3.12.0` driver is used, where `aggregate()` methods return [AggregatePublisher](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams/1.12/javadoc/com/mongodb/reactivestreams/client/AggregatePublisher.html).

The instance of `AggregatePublisher` is wrapped with some vertx class and passed as `result()` into the runCommand `handler`:

```
mongoClient.runCommand("aggregate", command, res -> {
  if (res.succeeded()) {
    JsonArray resArr = res.result().getJsonArray("result");
})
```

So, you don't have to worry about cursor and your query shouldv'e worked just fine, if you would try it out in the 1st place BEFORE posting your SO question.